# Is cooler included in Intel® Boxed Intel® Core™ i7-2600 Processor?

Tags: cpu, thermal-paste

I would like to know if cooler and thermal paste included in Intel® Boxed Intel® Core™ i7-2600 Processor? Or should I order cooler and thermal paste separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, Intel boxed (retail) processors come with a heatsink/fan.  The product pages for the [i7-2600](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115071) and [i7-2600k](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115070) at Newegg say heatsink and fan included.  The heatsink will have thermal material installed already (probably a pad).

Comment: Correct. That is what boxed means when it comes to Intel processors.